# Dingo with Laravel doesn't show errors

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, dingo-api

I've got a problem with Dingo and Laravel 5.4, I'm getting `HTTP 500 Internal Error` without any other details (blank chrome/postman page) even if I got in `config/app.php`:

```
'debug' => true,
'env' => 'local',
```

and in `config/api.php`:

```
'debug' => true,
```

Why it doesn't render typical laravel errors? :(

Comment: Check the apache error log.

Comment: It may not be getting to a point in execution where laravel can present an error. Check your php error logs, or look in storage/log/laravel.log

Comment: Okay, it was bad perrmisions for laravel log file ... thanks :)